# How are errors/failures handled in automated Azure Resource Group deployments?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell, azure-resource-manager, azure-deployment

I have read various articles on [automatically deploying resources groups](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/10/04/automating-azure-resource-group-deployment-using-a-service-principal-in-visual-studio-online-buildrelease-management/) in Azure, including the use of  [templates](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/resource-group-template-deploy/) and how to [troubleshoot](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/resource-manager-troubleshoot-deployments-portal/) failed deployments.

What is not clear in those articles is what rollback capabilities are in built if any, and/or the best way to revert the resource infrastructure back to the last successful state in the event of errors midway through the deployment.

For example, in Octopus Deploy there is the notion of certain build steps that are only triggered in the event of failure which essentially put everything back the way it was before the deployment started.

I can see that it is possible to "validate" your templates and infrastructure by running the `Test-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment` cmdlet to reduce potential errors before actually running the deployment, and also that it is possible to view the provisioning state following deployment by running `Get-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment`:

[image]

from which I could check for the `failed` status and conditionally run a script to clean up after the failure.

However, is there anything built in to cater for this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

While it is possible to roll a deployment over the top of an existing environment. The primary purpose of templates is (or appears to be) to deploy a new environment.

Which means that if something fails along the way, you delete the whole thing and start again. Or create your own logic to go in and figure out why. The only thing that Azure will do in the event of a failure is to report it to you. It is then up to you to make the decision about how you will react to that.

My personal approach is to deploy the basic building blocks via templates (so VMs, storage, etc) and then have a configuration management engine take over the more complex tasks of deploying software, and defining the configuration. Something that does have the intelligence to roll things back and repair them.

Comment: ARM templates are idempotent, meaning that you can re-deploy the same script immediately after an initial deployment and you will get the same result (no changes). If you decide to add another VM to your template and re-deploy, the existing VMs will remain and the new one will be added.

Comment: @Lewis the problem is that the results of rolling a modified template across an existing infrastructure are inconsistent. It isn't always clear what will be modified and what will be ignored. Azure seems to do a check for the existence of the top level resource (i.e. the VM, but will ignore any property settings such as additional disks, etc) So yes you can add a VM, but anything more subtle than that and you're going to run into issues

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've put together. It may help but basically you have to throw your own error as the result from Test-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment is null for success but has an object when it fails.

```
Do{
   Try{
       Write-Output "Testing Deployment..."
       If ($TestResult = Test-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -TemplateFile $VMTemplatePath -TemplateParameterObject $VMDeploymentParameters) {
          Throw "Testing failed.`r`n$($TestResult.Message)`r`n"
       }
       Write-Output "Testing complete."
       $TestResponse = "N"
   }
   Catch{
       Write-Output $_
       If ($TestResponse = (Read-Host "Would you like to try again? Y/N.") -ne "Y") { Exit }
   }
}
While($TestResponse -eq "Y")
```

Cheers

Lewis